# Geometric distribution values in Forest Fire generation model

Tags: python, random, distribution, igraph, geometric-mean

I am trying to do implementation (Python) of the Forest Fire graph generation algorithm (http://cs.stanford.edu/~jure/pubs/powergrowth-kdd05.pdf).

Here is how pseudo-code looks like: [image: pseudo-code of FF model] 
The problem I am having with is understanding the second step. How to generate these numbers?

There is an implementation in numpy library https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.geometric.html but it requires not just p value but also size (size of what in case of this algorithm? Why in the algorithms are given geometric means, why not just p value?)

I found one solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083170/7127824 but I am not sure it works right (according to the needs of this algorithm)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Since you need only one number from each distribution, the size is naturally 1.

Comment: More concretely, just call `numpy.random.geometric(p / (1 - p))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
numpy.random.geometric(p / (1 - p))
```